# clojure: search in vector of maps

Tags: clojure

I want to pass first-name and last-name to get age in clojure. what's the best way?

```
(def data
  [{:id 1 :first-name "John1" :last-name "Dow1" :age 14}
   {:id 2 :first-name "John2" :last-name "Dow2" :age 54}
   {:id 3 :first-name "John3" :last-name "Dow3" :age 34}])
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with? Note though that a vector of maps isn't the ideal way to store that information. A map of maps would allow for much easier lookups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(def data
  [{:id 1 :first-name "John1" :last-name "Dow1" :age 14}
   {:id 2 :first-name "John2" :last-name "Dow2" :age 54}
   {:id 3 :first-name "John3" :last-name "Dow3" :age 34}])


(defn find-user [first-name last-name data]
  (first (filter (fn [item]
                   (and (= (:first-name item) first-name)
                        (= (:last-name item) last-name)))
                 data)))

(:age (find-user "John3" "Dow3" data)) ;; => 34
```

Comment: That get you only the first one, I would recommend dropping ```first```.